# Reactor and database transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, reactor

I'm working on a java project, using spring boot as container, and to supply the fact the connection to Oracle database is no reactive, we decided to use reactor to parallelize operation such as insert or update that are not dependent to one another (no foreign key relations among them).

Sometimes during the execution of the ParallelFlux, it laments loosing connection:

> org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 1001ms.

or simply it does not find data persisted before the ParallelFlux call, but not committed.

This behavior is random, using the same data as input.

What I'm wondering about is if the database transaction is thread safe and if the ParallelFlux is treating it correctly.

Can anyone explain me how the database transaction is passed by spring boot to reactor and how the last handle it?

**EDIT**:

I did other tests. I monitored the connection on DB and noticed that the original transaction, the one where data is saved before the ParallelFlux block, is suspended and for each call of the method inside the ParallelFlux block, there is a new connection open and in wait for the original one to end. All this ended up as a lock on Oracle and then the reason for the *org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException*, due to connection saturation.

Knowing that, I changed the @Transactional annotation of the method called by the ParallelFlux, to:

```
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

Doing this it result in a org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException at the first call of the method, as expected.

**Change of Tags**

Someone asked to remove "reactor" from the tag list of this question, but it is not correct, because I'm using Reactor and not spring-webflux and this part is in the backend, not inside a REST service.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This isn't really answerable in its current form. It could be an issue with your reactor implementation (wild guess, perhaps you're using too few threads and too many requests, and your connections are timing out ‍♂️), an issue with your Hikari configuration, an issue with the underlying database, an issue with your network connection between your app and db layer, or something else entirely.

Comment: Without going deep in my project is there any documentation I can read to understand how spring boot and reator handle a database transaction? For now to me is sufficient to understand how they work.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, they don't really hand it natively at all - they'll be delegating to some other code to handle the connections. All I'd really suggest is to try creating the same problem with fewer dependencies (i.e. without reactor, then without spring boot, etc.) to see if you can narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do some tests trying to simplify the project and see if I come up with a solution or a deeper understanding of how they work.

Comment: Do you use reactive relational database connectivity, to connect to oracle?

Comment: I'm currently using hikari for the connection pool and NamedParameterJdbcTemplate for queries. I found some article on reactive database connection, but most of them referencing to Mongo. R2DBC is still in beta and hasn't an Oracle driver.

Comment: Indeed, I had problems with transactions when I made my calls to the database inside a reactive process. I tested with R2DBC and it works very well, but as you said earlier R2DBC is still in beta. So, to overcome the problems of the transaction, all calls to the database must be blocking in the transactional method, then I can follow with reactive treatments. I know this is not the best solution, but for the moment, with the relational database it will be a little complicated to have some reactive treatments.

Comment: Here is how you will be able to manage transactions using R2DBC: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/reference/r2dbc-transactions.adoc
if you want, add a piece of code of your problem so that we can analyze it...

Comment: As you can see from https://r2dbc.io/ there is no drivers for Oracle and I cannot go in production with a library in beta. There is no way out of R2DBC to pass the database transaction to a ParallelFlux, so I needed to commit the first part to get the reactor part working, obtaining in this way different and independent transactions.